# Why are HTML entities ignoring my span code in Outlook 2003 and IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, html-email, outlook-2003

**The setting:**

- HTML emails

**The guest list:**

- Outlook 2000 (desktop client)
- Outlook 2003 (desktop client)
- Outlook 2007 (desktop client)
- Outlook 2010 (desktop client)
- Outlook (Firefox, Chrome, Explorer)
- Gmail (Firefox, Chrome, Explorer)
- Yahoo (Firefox, Chrome, Explorer)
- Internet Explorer 7 browser (FML)

**My code:**

`<span style="font-size:85%;line-height:0;vertical-align:3px;">&reg;</span>`

I can't use any sort of `<sup>` tag because it doesn't render consistently despite any styling I could add.

**The question:**

Why is Outlook 2003 and IE7 adding extra line space above my code only on HTML entities?

**What I know so far:**

I can throw numbers and words in between my span tags and it's all good everywhere.  Same size, same positioning, same line height.  I tried switching switching to decimal entities but the results remained the same.  For example, for ® I use `&reg;` but also tried `&#174;`.  I even said "to hell with proper coding practices" and put a ® symbol straight in my HTML code.  Nothin'!

So then I thought maybe it had something to do with those entities being round (I mean I dunno, I'm trying everything) so I swapped in † (`&dagger;`) and ‡(`&Dagger;`) but it didn't change anything.

**For visual pleasure**

[image]

The above screenshot was taken in Outlook 2003.

(Note: some words have been changed for privacy reasons)

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the font-size and line-height of `<sup>` elements by adding style inline to the `<sup>` tag. Another CSS property that can help is [baseline-shift](http://css-infos.net/property/baseline-shift)

Personally I gave up on trying to get consistent results from `<sup>` in Outlook and other email clients, as some respect one CSS element while others do not.

The most consistent result I got (where the whole line height wasn't effected) was by creating a small image, avoiding using superscript characters all together.

Comment: The problem with `<sup>` tags is that they don't render the same in Outlook 2007 and 2010.  I've tried adjusting the font-size and line-height using inline CSS styling on the `<sup>` tag but it was inconsistant across the clients, namely the before mentioned ones.  I just tried `baseline-shift` as well and while `baseline-shift:sub` had a small impact, the line height was still a little bloated and noticeable.

Comment: @TimothyAdams Try using baseline shift with a +/- pixel value instead. But as mentioned, you still won't get consistent results across all email clients which is why a small image is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The code below has always rendered properly for me in your list of clients.  Maybe try using px instead of percent in the font-size.

```
<sup style="font-size:10px; line-height:0; vertical-align:3px;">&reg;</sup>
```

Comment: This is what I originally had which led me to my current code.  The problem with this is that the font-size isn't actually 100% (10px in this case) in Outlook 2007 and 2010, it's about 70% of the size it should be.  Not really an issue unless the text you're superscripting is already small, then it become illegible.

Answer (score 0):

If you use span tag instead of sup tag (and give it all the parameters you have above, including font-size and vertical-align, which is the only thing that sup would normally do outside of OUTLOOK's messed up little world), this should keep results in other email clients and OUTLOOK looking more similar.